# IE 11 find on this page not working for embedded SVG

Tags: svg, search, internet-explorer-11

**Problem:** Search on SVG file is failing in IE 11 when embedded inside an HTML file.

**Explanation:** Below is the sample code where I am embedding an SVG file in an HTML file using `<object>` tag
e.g.;

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="SVGViewer1" data="TestSVG.svg" type="image/svg+xml" VIEWASTEXT>
        <DIV id=RasterDiv>
        <div class="svgmessage">This page requires an SVG viewer.<br><br>See the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) Web site for more information on SVG and available viewers.</div>
        </div>
</object>
```

I want to do the "Find on this page Ctrl F" operation to search the content of SVG.

**Observations:** "Find on this page `Ctrl F` doesn't work in IE 11 and Edge browsers. SVG is perfectly searchable in Chrome. I have also observed that if you directly open the SVG file in the browser (no embedding inside HTML file) then `Ctrl F` works in IE 11 and Edge too.

**Question:**

1. Why search inside the SVG file is not working in IE11 if you embed in an HTML file?
2. Any workaround to solve this?

Comment: I made a test with chrome, IE and Edge. I find that I am only able to see the content of SVG using developer tools in chrome. If I try to search the content of SVG using Web page than it is not searchable(in Chrome too). I find that I am not able to see SVG content using developer tools in IE and Edge. If I open the SVG file directly in IE or Edge than contents are visible through developer tools. Currently, It looks like by design. I will try to provide a feedback regarding this to MS Edge developers. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your test. With me,  "find" works in chrome for text boxes (but do not work  inside shapes)

Comment: Because shape is displayed as a graphic. which we can see on the interface. So we cannot search inside shapes.

Comment: Yes. That's correct but Chrome can find the content of text boxes but IE can't..

Comment: I see, I will also try to provide a feedback for this request for MS Edge. Microsoft had stopped providing any feature update for IE so we cannot expect to have this feature update for IE. Thanks for your understanding.